# Get only second record from details table

Tags: sql-server

I have a details table (AppID, SSN). I want to get only second where the record repeats. 
[image]

I have pointed with red the values that I want to get. Please tell me the query in MS SQL.

Comment: So you don't want any results where the record doesn't repeat? i.e. for `16417,16418,16419`? Also second ordered by what? There is no default ordering of records you can use.

Comment: Yes I only want second record else null. There's no order of the records in table

Comment: @hotcoder you should be more clearer next time:)

Comment: `I want second...there's no order`: can you see the contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### edit

```
select AppID, SSN ,rn from (
select AppID, SSN , row_number() over(partition by AppID order by  AppID) as rn from Table
)T where rn=2
```

Comment: This won't get "only the second record". It will get the last record.

Comment: @MartinSmith he wanted the single records + the last record from the duplicates... no ? the question is not clear then

Comment: I have only 2 columns in the table.

Comment: Who knows? Doesn't look like it from their clarification though.